# why does it complain integer constant is too large for its type

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

**I am writing a hamming weight calculator but why does the number 3 is too large for uint32_t ?**

Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and returns the number of '1' bits it has (also known as the Hamming weight).

Note:

Note that in some languages, such as Java, there is no unsigned integer type. In this case, the input will be given as a signed integer type. It should not affect your implementation, as the integer's internal binary representation is the same, whether it is signed or unsigned.

In Java, the compiler represents the signed integers using 2's complement notation. Therefore, in Example 3, the input represents the signed integer. -3.

```
// package LeetCode Problem.Problem 2;
// Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and returns the number of '1'
// bits it has (also known as the Hamming weight).

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int hammingWeight(uint32_t n);

class BitShifting {
 public:
  uint32_t n;
  int hammingWeight(uint32_t n);
  void setn(uint32_t n);
};

void BitShifting::setn(uint32_t n) {
  n = n;
}

int BitShifting::hammingWeight(uint32_t n) {
  int count = 0;
  while (n) {  // while n > 0
    count += n & 1;  // n&1 is a bit comparison for binary ends; returns 0 or 1
                     // that if true would += 1;
    n = n >> 1;  // Shift n to the right for one bit
  }
  return count;
}

int main() {
  BitShifting n1, n2, n3;
  n1.n = 00000000000000000000000000001011;
  n2.n = 00000000000000000000000010000000;
  n3.n = 11111111111111111111111111111101;

  cout << endl
       << "The hamming weight of Input 1 is: " << n1.hammingWeight(n1.n) << endl
       << "The hamming weight of Input 2 is: " << n2.hammingWeight(n2.n) << endl
       << "The hamming weight of Input 3 is: " << n3.hammingWeight(n3.n);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `11111111111111111111111111111101` is a huge number.

Comment: `11111111111111111111111111111101` is a decimal value, not a binary one, because it doesn't have a leading `0b`.   It's representation needs at least 104 bits - which is bigger that a `uint32_t` can represent.   In fact, there are few real-world compilers with a built-in integral type which can hold that value.    Incidentally, the values being assigned to `n1.n` and `n2.n` are octal values, not binary - so probably are not giving the result you intend.

Comment: As as side note, the better API would be `class BitShift { public:  BitShift(uint32_t nn) : n{nn} {}; int hamming() const; uint32_t n; };` -- `setN` should be done at construction and the method returning the Hamming-weight should probably use the member variable (instead of one provided as an argument). `static int hamming(uint32_t)` is an option, but not as good IMO, since the class is used to store the parameter and the related methods...

Comment: I'll bet you could remove almost all of that code and still show the problem. Try it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enter literals in binary format you need to have the prefix `0b`, as in `0b11111111111111111111111111111101`.

For comparison, `0` is the prefix for octal numbers (011 is not even 11 decimal, it's decimal 9) and `0x` is the prefix for hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `11111111111111111111111111111101` is a decimal number.

You probably want a binary number: `0b11111111111111111111111111111101`

In addition to that, your `setn` member function doesn't work. `n = n` assignes the local `n` to the local `n`. To assign to the member variable, either change the name of the local variable or assign it like below:

```
void BitShifting::setn(uint32_t n) {
  this->n = n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void BitShifting::setn(uint32_t n) {
  n = n;
}
```

The method argument `n` shadows the class member variable `n`. So this function does nothing. Rename the argument or the member variable.

Comment: rename or clarify  this->n = n: